# scp /var/log/httpd on amazon linux

Tags: scp

I am trying to do:

```
scp ec2-user@php-pos-web-1:/var/log/httpd/* tmp/php-pos-web-1;
```

I get permission denied because those files are owned by root. I don't want to enable root login. Is it ok if I change the group for that folder? What is the best way?

I am on amazon linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not a good idea to change the permissions to system folders. They are not world-readable for a reason. They can expose potentially sensitive data (accessed pages, clients IP addresses, ...).

You should on the other way copy the files to some some accessible location (`/tmp`) using `sudo` and then copy them over the network back.

Comment: Thanks; I coped to /tmp and it worked great as it was read permissions for all